# How to handle dependencies when using the pub/sub pattern

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe

When using the Publish/Subscribe pattern I sometimes face a disadvantage: [the semantic coupling it creates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern#Inflexible_Semantic_coupling) between parts of the system. I'm using it for web development, specifically JavaScript-heavy web applications.

What ways are there to reduce, explicitize or remove the `FORM` module's dependency (on the `VALIDATION` module) as shown in the example below?

```
var Event = require('some-pub-sub-library'); // E.g. github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

var events = {
  formBeforeSubmit: 'form/beforeSubmit',
  formSubmit: 'form/submit',
  validation: 'validation/go',
  validationOk: 'validation/ok'
};

(function() { // FORM MODULE
  var submit = false;

  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    if (submit == false) {
      // For the validation to do its thing
      Event.publish(events.formBeforeSubmit);
      return false; // Don't submit the form
    }
    return true;
  });

  // The validation should publish this event
  Event.subscribe(events.submit, function() {
    submit = true;
    $('form').trigger('submit');
  });
}());

(function() { // VALIDATION MODULE
  Event.subscribe(events.formBeforeSubmit, function() {
    if ($('input').val() == 'foo')
      Event.publish(events.submit); // Validation passed
    else
      alert('Validation didn\'t pass.');
  });
}());
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your pubsub library is synchronous and does no caching, the `Event.subscribe(events.submit, …)` needs to happen before the `Event.publish(events.formBeforeSubmit)`?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, actually it will be subscribed before published, since the publish depends on a user interaction (submitting the form). My current library is async, but I would consider to switch to sync if that would help me with decoupling modules from each other!

Comment: No, I don't mean the subscription for the validation (`formBeforeSubmit`), but the subscription *in* that form submit handler, which waits for the result of the validation. Your pub sub only works because your library is async, however in that case the `return submit == true` always yields false

Comment: @Bergi I've edited. Does it make more sense now?